# Where can I go with reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Many people here on Stack Overflow have a big reputation, and they are really used frequently in this place.

Sometimes I ask my self, and I think many of us also:

- Where can this member go with this reputation?
- Can some companies based on this reputation for the recruitment, if yes what this companies for example?
- Can you share with the new members some experience of why this is
  important or this is just for **fun**?
- #### What about the recruitment of Stack Exchange company? Is it based on this reputation for example, and is the company propose some jobs of some members?

Comment: I wouldn't bank on it, but I have gotten interviews on the sole basis of my SO reputation (at the time it was around 12k)

Comment: `Where can this member go with this reputation?` to hell? ███ themselves? So many choices :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123918/what-is-the-benefit-of-reputation-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Related: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20407/will-high-reputation-in-stack-overflow-help-to-get-a-good-job

Comment: Related: https://www.quora.com/Does-having-a-good-Stack-Exchange-Stack-Overflow-reputation-improve-your-chances-of-employment

Comment: i see so this is important, can any one share with us some experiment with this?

Comment: @Gimby I _think_ they mean "experience" . If someone can share it, if they have experience with this (like Sayse does in their comment and answer).

Comment: @Gimby sorry, i mean experience not experiment, baaaaadddd

Comment: I suppose you could try it as a pickup line: "hey there beautiful, you know I've got over 10,000 reputation points on Stack Overflow?  Can I but you a drink?  "

Comment: @carpetsmoker probably has more success than *"If I would say you have a beautiful body, would you hold it against me?"*

Comment: For me, it's the Executive Bathroom Island that makes it all worth. [Totally.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1t1OVRfmMik&t=1m11s)

Answer (score 6):

The reputation is just a number at the end of the day, its what you learn along the road of gaining the reputation that is important.

Whilst visiting the site, you learn *a lot* of useful stuff that you are able to apply to your developments and that is what is really important.

The number does look very nice to some recruiters that understand Stack Overflow, but a lot of people in HR still don't understand how developers use it.

As stated in comments, I wouldn't bank on it, but I have gotten interviews on the sole basis of my SO reputation (at the time it was around 12k) - I know this because a person I know working at this company said they were going to ignore my cv until they found out about my reputation.

Comment: *"I know this because a person I know working at this company were going to ignore my cv until they found out about my reputation."* - either they were morons or your CV needed work :)

Comment: @Gimby - I've since updated my cv :) (and I didn't take the job they were going to offer so don't know if that says something either..)

Comment: Wow, they haven't told you about the special high-reputation only members club? Such great parties...